# Consolidate two or more columns of data into one column using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to collect Sch Code from different columns into one column as shown below.

First priority is by formula or UDF Function if possible.

**My Data**:

```
Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D    Column E    Column F    Column G  
SCH Code    Value       SCH Code    Value       Rating      SCH Code    Value
C01-3-1     4           C01-4-1     8           300         C02-3-1     8
                                                300         C02-3-5     9
C01-3-2     5           C01-4-2     12          300         C02-3-2     12
C01-3-3     6           C01-4-3     21          300         C02-3-3     21
                                                300         C02-3-6     10
C01-3-4     7           C01-4-4     4           300         C02-3-4     4
```

**Required Result** (Only Sch Code required in summary sheet but it is required by formula or VBA UDF function) :

```
Column A

C01-3-1                     
C01-3-2                     
C01-3-3                     
C01-3-4                     
C01-4-1                     
C01-4-2                     
C01-4-3                     
C01-4-4                     
C02-3-1                     
C02-3-5                     
C02-3-2                     
C02-3-3                     
C02-3-6                     
C02-3-4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can collect unique non-blank values from column A with an *array formula* e.g. `=INDEX($A$2:$A$99,MATCH(0, IF(LEN($A$2:$A$99),COUNTIF(I$1:I1,$A$2:$A$99),1),0))`. Since this returns `#N/A` where it has no more values to return from its column, you can pass control over to a similar formula that references another column with `IFERROR`.

[image]

To choose from your three columns of SCH Codes, you would need to stack this 3 deep. The formula in I2 is:

```
=IF(LEN(I1),IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$99,MATCH(0, IF(LEN($A$2:$A$99),COUNTIF(I$1:I1,$A$2:$A$99),1),0)),IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$99,MATCH(0, IF(LEN($C$2:$C$99),COUNTIF(I$1:I1,$C$2:$C$99),1),0)),IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F$99,MATCH(0, IF(LEN($F$2:$F$99),COUNTIF(I$1:I1,$F$2:$F$99),1),0)),""))),"")
```

This *array formula* requires *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*, not just *Enter*. Once entered correctly, it can be filled down to catch all possible values. I would fill down for at least three times as many rows as you have in order that the blanks would have a place if they were filled in at a later date.

In theory, you could stack this much deeper but for practical purposes, I wouldn't go much deeper than this. Array formulas eat up calculation resources at a logarithmic rate so the size of your data is going to be a key factor on whether this is a suitable solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot and its work very correct as i required.... but most of the people do not know how to handle this much long formula ... is it possible to make a user define function and we just select the columns with that function and our result will come.

Comment: @ShahbazNawaz - If 'people' do not know how to handle a formula then they should get off their lazy backsides and learn how instead of coming to a public help forum and asking someone to do their work for them. To answer your question, yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

Copy and paste all values in column C below column A data. Highlight column A and go to Data>Remove duplicates then Data>Sort.